# ¿Cómo puedo enviar tres variables desde AJAX a un archivo PHP

Tags: php, ajax

Estoy haciendo una consulta con PHP y AJAX pero quiero enviar tres variables para hacer la consulta pero solo me envía una variable, en mi código si mando "valor" si lo puedo recoger en mi otro archivo PHP pero "valor2" y "valor3" no se envían, ¿Cómo puedo enviar esas tres variables a un archivo PHP?

```
function MostrarConsulta(datos) {
    divResultado = document.getElementById('resultado');
    valor = document.consulta.datosCaja.value;
    valor2 = document.consulta.datosCaja2.value;
    valor3 = document.consulta.datosCaja3.value;

    ajax = objetoAjax();
    //ajax.open("GET", datos);
    ajax.open("POST", "conexion/consultaAjax.php",true);
    ajax.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (ajax.readyState == 4) {
        divResultado.innerHTML = ajax.responseText
    }
}

ajax.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
//enviando los valores
ajax.send("datos="+valor)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El formato para enviar datos por `post` es así:

```
ajax.send('datos=' + valor + '&datos2=' + valor2 + '&datos3=' + valor3);
```

https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp

Answer (score 0):

Me parece que solo estas enviado una variable en `ajax.send("datos="+valor)` puedes crear un objeto de `js` y asi envias las tres.

```
var myObjetc = {
   valor  : document.consulta.datosCaja.value,
   valor2 : document.consulta.datosCaja2.value,
   valor3 : document.consulta.datosCaja3.value
};
```

y luego solo envias el objeto

```
ajax.send("datos="+myObjetc);
```

**Editado**

Verifica que document.consulta.x.value este arrojando un valor, en caso de que no funcione puedes intentarlo de esta forma

```
"valor1="+valor1+"&valor2="+valor2...
```

En caso de que no funcione, te recomiendo usar jquery, facilita las cosas

```
$.ajax({
    headers: {'csrftoken': $('input[name = _token]').val()},
    url: 'tuUrl',
    type: 'POST, GET,...',
    dataType: 'json, html, ...',
    data: myObjetc,//objeto con los valores
    beforeSend: function(){
        //cosas que pasan antes de que se envien los datos.
    },
    success: function(response){
         //cosas que pasan cuando ajax funciono correctamente.
    },
    error: function(){
        //cosas que pasan en caso de error.
    }
});
```

y los recibes tal como los estas recibiendo.

Comment: Hola, ya lo intente como me mencionas pero el error sigue, cree el objeto como en tu ejemplo:

var myObjetc = {
    valor  : document.consulta.datosCaja.value,
    valor2 : document.consulta.datosCaja2.value,
    valor3 : document.consulta.datosCaja3.value
 };

y lo envié de la siguiente forma:

ajax.send("datos="+myObjetc)

Pero al recibir los datos en el archivo PHP me llegan vacíos, así es como los recibo:

$variable = $_POST['valor'];
$variable2 = $_POST['valor2'];
$variable3 = $_POST['valor3'];

Answer (score 0):

Si las estás enviando por `POST` puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
ajax.send("datos=" + valor + "&nueva=" + nueva + "&otra=" + otra);
```

Si las estás enviando por `GET` puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
xhttp.open("GET", "conexion/consultaAjax.php?datos=valor&nueva=nueva", true);
```